# MVC 5 - Infinite Loop or recursion on GET - Reflection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing in MVC 5, and I am receiving an error on a GET that can return multiple records (900+).

This page also POSTs a multiple row update, but I am receiving the infinite loop on the GET.   If the page has a lot of records returned (120ish+), I get the infinite loop error.  It doesn't seem to happen on pages with fewer records (<100), but even still, the page takes longer to load than I would expect.

Here is the error:

- Make sure you don't have an infinite loop or infinite recursion
- System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
  Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
- I am not getting an error on a particular line, but at one point in the disassembly, I saw an error string.EqualsHelper(string, string) + 0x0000000c in process iisexpress.exe.  (This doesn't happen everytime the page crashes)

Is there a problem with my code, or is the problem the number of records returned to the page?  There are sometimes 900 records on a page.  I could add pagination, but having all records on one page is more efficient for the user.  The user bulk sets a field value on the page, and then changes the bulk set value for a varied amount of records.

I have tried both a for and a foreach loop, but I had the same error using both methods (and I am not sure what is the best to use in this circumstance).

I have been working on this for awhile, and I am not finding the problem.

Controller

```
public ActionResult PCPList(string location, string pcp) 
{
    List<PCPListVM> data = new List<PCPListVM>();
    //query
    data = (from n in db.DataDump                
            join t in db.TData on n.SubscriberID equals t.SubscriberID into joinedTable
            from td in joinedTable.Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where n.PCP == pcp
            orderby n.MemberName
            select new PCPListVM()
            {
                ID = n.ID,
                MemberName = n.MemberName,
                DateOfBirth = n.DateOfBirth,
                PCP = n.PCP,   
                Location = td.Location,
                LocationList = db.LocationList.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.LocationID,
                    Text = c.LocationList,
                    Selected = c.LocationList.Equals(location)
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Text);
            }).ToList();
    return View(data);
}
```

View

```
@model List<Project.ViewModels.PCPListVM>
// loop through records
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@j</td>
            <td>@i.SubscriberID</td>
            <td>@i.MemberName</td>
            <td>@i.DateOfBirth</td>
            <td>@i.PCP</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Location, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.location, "", new { @class = "input-sm" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        j++;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class PCPListVM
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string SubscriberID { get; set; }      
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PCP { get; set; }        
    public string Location { get; set; }       
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
}
```

Update -

My test case returns 1200 rows.   I have also tried removing the dropdowns altogether to see if they were the issue and the page is still crashing. I have checked in the controller and the correct amount of records are being returned to the viewmodel.

After running the profiler, I am seeing this message: System.Reflection.*.Get.*(.*) = 9.01; You may be using Reflection excessively. It is an expensive operation.

Is there a better way for me to pull this data and loop through it?

The error that I see in the call stack is : System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetId(System.RuntimeTypeHandle)

Comment: What is `pcp` in `where n.PCP == pcp`?

Comment: oops - I return more fields than what I display, I just cut it down for readability.  The pcp string is a passed parameter.  I added it in.  That parameter comes from a dropdownlist populated by the database.

Comment: Can you run this under the debugger? The call stack window shows you the stack overflow reason.

Comment: The error that I see: System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetId(System.RuntimeTypeHandle)

Answer (score 0):

When doing the LocationList creation, do this:

```
LocationList = db.LocationList.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.LocationID,
                    Text = c.LocationList,
                    Selected = c.LocationList.Equals(location)
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList()
```

I'm thinking that Json.NET is having some circular reference problems when trying to serialize the IEnumerable response.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. I have also tried removing the dropdowns altogether to see if they were the issue and the page is still crashing.  I have checked in the controller and the correct amount of records are being returned to the viewmodel.  I wonder if something is wrong with the looping in my view.  This is the first time that I have done the bulk update.

Comment: 1200 records are returned,

Comment: This code seems fine to me. Can you please make sure that you dispose the database connection after the request is completed? It may be that the error is triggered by something else in the background.

Comment: This shows my newbie-ness.  I have this at the end of my controller, but nothing in the ActionResult itself:
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

Comment: The disassembly just showed an error: dword ptr es:[edi]

Comment: These are pretty cryptic errors, we need to figure out the root in the managed code. Is there anything else running along in your application besides this simple HTTP request?

Comment: not that I am aware of.  Is there a way for me to check this?

Comment: You can start profiling your application: VS has some built-in tools for this. Google it :)

Comment: What should I be looking for in particular?  The page did load on IE (but no Chrome, surprisingly).  The CPU maxed out at 100%.  The function that took the most was System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d_1'1.MoveNext()

Ex: DA0504: (Maximum)Working Set = 55,279,616.00; This rule is for information only. The Process Working Set counter measures physical memory usage by the process you are profiling. The value reported is the maximum observed over all measurement intervals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97143/discussion-between-daniela-and-tamas-ionut).

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the number of records returned was causing a performance issue in this case.  I ended up returning my records to a WebGrid and paging by 200, and I am no longer receiving the error messages.